# weka AdaBoost does not improve results

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, weka, bayesian, adaboost

In my bachelor thesis I am supposed to use AdaBoostM1 with a MultinomialNaiveBayes classifier on a text classification problem. The problem is that in most cases, the M1 is worse or equal to the MultinomialNaiveBayes without boosting.

I use the following code:

```
AdaBoostM1 m1 = new AdaBoostM1();
m1.setClassifier(new NaiveBayesMultinomial());
m1.buildClassifier(training);
```

So I don't get how the AdaBoost would not be able to improve the results? Unfortunately, I couldn't find anything else about that on the web as most people seem to be very satisfied with the AdaBoost.

Comment: so it seems the solution is that boosting only makes sense if the classifier makes mistakes on its own training data. as Naive Bayes usually achieves accuracies close to 100 %, boosting does not make sense here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AdaBoost is a binary/dichotomous/2-class classifier and designed to boost a weak learner that is just better than 1/2 accuracy.  AdaBoostM1 is a M-class classifier but still requires the weak learner to be better than 1/2 accuracy, when one would expect chance level to be around 1/M. Balancing/weighting is used to get equal prevalence classes initially, but the reweighting inherent to AdaBoost can destroy this quickly.  A solution is to base boosting on chance corrected measures like Kappa or Informedness (AdaBook).

As M grows, e.g. with text classification, this mismatch grows, and thus a much stronger than chance classifier is needed. Thus with M=100, chance is about 1% but 50% minimum accuracy is needed by AdaBoostM1.

As base classifiers get stronger (viz. no longer barely above chance) the scope for boosting to improve things reduces - it has already pulled us to a very specific part of the search space. It is increasingly likely to have overfitted to errors and outliers, so there is no scope to balance a wide variety of variants.

A number of resources on informedness (including matlab code and xls sheets and early papers) are here: http://david.wardpowers.info/BM A comparison with other chance-corrected kappa measures is here: http://aclweb.org/anthology-new/E/E12/E12-1035.pdf

A weka implementation and experimentation for Adaboost using Bookmaker informedness is available - contact author.

Answer (score 4):

It's hard to beat Naive Bayes on text classification. Furthermore, boosting was designed for weak classifiers with high [bias](http://www.aiaccess.net/English/Glossaries/GlosMod/e_gm_bias_variance.htm) and that's where boosting performs well. Boosting decreases bias but increases variance. Hence if you want the combo AdaBoost + Naive Bayes to outperform Naive Bayes you have to have a big training data set and cross the border, where enlarging of the training set doesn't further increase Naive Bayes's performance (while AdaBoost still benefits from the enlarged training data set).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! If I could, I would accept all three of them.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to read the following paper which examines boosting on Naive Bayes. It demonstrates that boosting does not improve the accuracy of the naive Bayesian classifier as much is usually expected in a set of natural domains:

http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/1467-8640.00219/abstract

Hope it provides a good insight.